# Response 302 http url service REST express.js

Tags: node.js, http, express

I have a node system developed in the framework and I express something strange happening with the REST service URL.

```
For example we had the URL users
    GET: / user
```

With the GET method we returned the user list.

But a few days ago we began sending the error 302, I was researching and refers to a temporary redirect.

if I make the request in this way

```
GET: / user /
```

With the diagonal end if I answered 200 ok,

But the weirdest thing if it worked before and all the url of my service I use it without the diagonal end and are working well.

The fastest solution I did is to change the name of the path on the other
example:

```
GET: / users
```

but this is not the right solution because other url few days ago we began to fail.

which it is the project

```
GET: / project
```

The REST API service is consumed by an angular client.
Data:
I am using the CORS package for crossdomain

```
//import
var cors = require ( 'cors');
// Apply to all requests
app.use (CORS ());
```

I hope you can help me find out that should this fail

Comment: please post your server side code so people can better help you

Comment: For consistency (which might matter to search engines), some servers choose to redirect a `/users` request to `/users/`.  And a 3xx status code is how this would be done.  Is that what is happening to you?  I'm having trouble figuring out what your question actually is.